# If I have been living in USA legally for 7 years and as permanent resident for one year, can I apply for citizenship?

Tags: usa

Basically that is the question. Does time spent living on a G4 visa count toward your 5 year requirement for citizenship at all?

How can I find out. I tried calling usics but they don't know anything beside basics.

Comment: No immigration status presence other than permanent residency counts.

Answer (score 3):

There's a handy [worksheet](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/Citizenship%20&%20Naturalization%20Based%20Resources/A%20Guide%20to%20Naturalization/PDFs/M-480.pdf) you can fill in. If you have been a permanent resident for fewer than three years, you are not eligible. For the rest, please check the worksheet.

Alternatively you can check the [Who Is Eligible for Naturalization?](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/article/chapter4.pdf) chapter of "A Guide to Naturalization".